# Git and SVN on the same system?

Tags: git, svn

We're currently using SVN with our own server, so I've got the SVN client and Ankh set up and working fine on my laptop with Visual Studio. I'd like to use git (with github) for personal projects and as a learning exercise.

Are there any potential problems doing both on the same PC (theoretical or actually seen)? 
Any recommendations on getting (*git*ting?) started?

Comment: Using git on your system is possible in any and every situation, it's not restricted in any way by other VCS clients installed. In addition, as Problematic noted below, Git has SVN integration so you could theoretically use git on your own computer and push revisions to SVN.

Comment: thanks to all for the answers (and thanks for the migrate - I struggled with the decision to put this in P. or SO.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't think of any problems, aside from having to use two VCS clients, but git actually has SVN integration, so really what you can (should?) do if you're looking to break into git is just use the git-svn bindings to consolidate down to one VCS client.

There's a "for-beginners" tutorial entitled [Effectively Using Git With Subversion](http://www.viget.com/extend/effectively-using-git-with-subversion/) that you can check out for a basic workflow and examples of how to use git-svn, and a [git > SVN migration crash course](http://git-scm.com/course/svn.html) on the official git-scm site that explains git equivalents to SVN commands you already know.

Comment: Beware that using git-svn will break SVN's merge tracking, if you are doing merges in git.

Answer (score 4):

It's no problem at all. Before I discovered git-svn, I was actually running a git repository on the contents of an SVN working directory, and after setting up the .*ignore files properly, neither ever knew about the other and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I use both systems (svn and git) locally at work. I use the git system because it is easy to branch and do experiments, and the svn system (everybody else uses it) for integrating with colleagues. This is the system I would recommend, since I have tried working with git-svn and it broke severely, I guess it has something to do with the size of the project, and me not getting all svn revisions (just the last 1000 or so).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would recommend to install [SubGit](http://subgit.com) into your SVN server. After that the SVN server will get additional Git interface to it. So those who prefer SVN will continue using SVN, those who use Git may use Git interface.

Answer (score -1):

GIT and SVN may serve the same functions(version control) but they have some key differances between them. THey also connect on differnt ports different folders and all that great stuff so they should run fun on the same machine the only issue you could have is some speed issues, just from a lot of IO read and writes that can take place because of that.